# how do i identify an xpath without indices

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code that scrapes info from a site, but I have to get rid of some cookies pop-ups first. To click the right buttons, I need their  XPaths (as far as I know). The problem is that a part of the XPath changes every time, and I don't know how to find them as they don't really have any attributes like an ID or something.

This is the HTML of the button:

```
<button class="Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 lcqSKB" style="visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(12, 44, 91);">Lees meer om voorkeuren te accepteren</button>
```

This is the command I'm using right now:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[14]/div[1]/div[3]/button').click()
```

And this is the XPath:

```
/html/body/div[VARIABLE]/div[1]/div[3]/button
```

where VARIABLE changes every time, so I changed the 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the full xPath like you are doing you will run into issues like that all the time. The better approach is to figure out another/shorter way to get to that element.

It is hard to test without the URL but try one of these:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0.lcqSKB")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some generic xpath:

```
/html/body/div[VARIABLE]/div[1]/div[3]/button

/*/button[@class="Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 lcqSKB"]
```

or

```
/*/button[contains(@class, 'Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0')]
```

results in:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/*/button[@class="Button__StyledButton-a1qza5-0 lcqSKB"]').click()
```

This approach helps identifying the element (button) no matter the variable in the full xpath.

For more infos regarding xpath syntax see:
[W3schools-xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)